# To use Doctrine entity attributes you'll need PHP 8, doctrine/orm 2.9, doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.4 and symfony/framework-bundle 5.2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem on my Symfony project version **4.4.9**, with PHP 8. when I run `php bin/console make:entity` these errors appear:

> To use Doctrine entity attributes you'll need PHP 8, doctrine/orm 2.9, doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.4 and
> symfony/framework-bundle 5.2.

composer.json

```
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.13",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.9.6",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*"
},
```

and my **PHP Version : 8.1**
[image: The error]

Comment: From the error everything matches except you will need to upgrade to *Symfony 5.2+* for Doctrine entity attributes to work...

Comment: That error also triggers if the mapping driver configured for your entities is *not* attribute. I cannot check right now if that's the definite cause in this instance under 8.1, but you can check your config with `bin/console debug:config doctrine  orm.entity_managers.default.mappings` (assuming a standard install), look for the key `type`, and change it to `attribute` in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` if necessary. Let me know if it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue running Symfony 4.4 + Symfony Maker Bundle under under PHP 8+.

I can reproduce the issue with a project created from scratch on PHP 8.

```
$ composer create-project symfony/skeleton maker-annotations ^4.4.0
$ cd maker-annotations
$ composer require doctrine symfony/maker-bundle
$ bin/console make:entity
```

This will consistently error out under PHP8. Funnily enough, you can call `make:entity` again over the same entity, and it will appear to work... but it will error out for some other reason in the end.

The only solution I could find was to downgrade PHP to 7.4. If you are using a version of Symfony **that** old, it might be safer to use an older version of PHP as well in any case.

Or better yet, simply upgrade your Symfony version to 5.2.